# launch file foreign_relay error

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a node for foreign relay to a remote computer turtlebot but it gives me this error.

```
[FATAL] [1486425646.037670123]: Couldn't parse the foreign master URI [http:] into a host:port pair.
[generic_msg_foreign_relay-1] process has died [pid 25027, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/multimaster_experimental/foreign_relay/bin/foreign_relay adv http: //192.168.1.17:11311 /leader/base_link /leader/base_link __name:=generic_msg_foreign_relay __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/4accea04-ecc0-11e6-856c-48d2246be9cd/generic_msg_foreign_relay-1.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/4accea04-ecc0-11e6-856c-48d2246be9cd/generic_msg_foreign_relay-1*.log
```

this is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="generic_msg_foreign_relay" pkg="foreign_relay" type="foreign_relay"
        args="adv http: //192.168.1.17:11311 /leader/base_link /leader/base_link" respawn="false">
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253940/launch-file-foreign_relay-error/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2017-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> args="adv http: //192.168.1.17:11311
> ```

If this is an actual copy/paste of your launch file, then you seem to have a space between `http:` and `//192.168.1.17:11311`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-02-09**:
thanks. I got it working now